# Read numbers in line one by one with O(1) space

Tags: python, memory, space-complexity

Many coding challenges have multiple numbers in the same line, often with a first line telling how many numbers there are in the multi-number line:

```
4
31 415 9 26
```

Usually I just read the entire line, then `.split()` it and map the strings to numbers.

**But is there a good way to *not* read the entire line at once, instead read one number at a time?** In order to save memory, either because I *can't* or don't *want* to read the whole line into memory. I'd like to only use O(1) space (let's assume numbers are small/bounded so they're O(1) size). Doesn't have to be absolutely minimal, for example if a solution internally reads a full 4 KB memory page at a time, that's ok, still O(1) and relatively small. For use case, think *millions* of numbers on one line, and a memory limit let's say below 1 MB.

In C++ I'd do it like this:

```cpp
int n;
std::cin >> n;
while (n--) {
    int value;
    std::cin >> value;
    // now do something with the value
}
```

I wrote this generator that takes a file object and gives me an iterator of strings. For the above example, it yields the strings `'4'`, `'31'`, `'415'`, `'9'` and `'26'`. It reads one character at a time, and splits at space characters as determined by `.isspace()`:

```
def split(file):
    value = []
    while char := file.read(1):
        if char.isspace():
            if value:
                yield ''.join(value)
            value.clear()
        else:
            value.append(char)
    if value:
        yield ''.join(value)
```

But that's of course ridiculously complicated and slow, and I don't even know whether this `str.isspace` usage is equivalent to what `str.split` considers whitespace. It just illustrates one way to achieve what I want.

Edit: Here's a *simpler* way, but still more complicated and slow than I'd like. I'm looking for some built-in way that does the low-level work for me, at C speed.

```
from itertools import groupby

def split(file):
    groups = groupby(iter(lambda: file.read(1), ''), str.isspace)
    for isspace, chars in groups:
        if not isspace:
            yield ''.join(chars)
```

Comment: Does [python readline with custom delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980776/python-readline-with-custom-delimiter) answer your question? (Make spaces be treated as a line delimiter, and there you are).

Comment: Have you run into a case when the memory is not enough for using just reading the line and using split?

Comment: You could use `re.finditer(r"\w+", s)`  which will provide an iterator.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No. I had actually looked into that, but `' '` is not allowed as delimiter. I tried, gets `ValueError: illegal newline value:  `.

Comment: @MarkMeyer And what is `s`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user may be?

Comment: @DaniMesejo No, but I've run into a case where I didn't *want* to do that. For a coding challenge where I'd otherwise only need O(1) space.

Comment: Hmm. Does read-only file-mapped memory count against your space usage, for purposes of this challenge? :)

Comment: @venky__ Seems similar to what I used in my generator, so has the same issues.

Comment: @MarkMeyer 's suggestion to use `finditer` would be good. It still reads one by one but it would do so in compiled code and you're only reading 3 or so at a time anyway.

Comment: In fact, why do you want to avoid reading one by one? At best you could be reading three by three, which isn't much better.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess you mean memory-mapped file? :-) I'm not exactly familiar with that, but if that takes only a relatively small amount of memory, that'd be ok, yes. I considered trying that in combination with `re.finditer`, but that's documented as wanting a string, so I gave that up.

Comment: Heh. The main point of mmap'ing your input file is that it isn't really memory allocated to your process at all; instead, you're getting pages from the operating system's block cache. So it's really a question of how whatever tools are being used to measure your answer's memory allocation work; it's _conceivable_ that they wouldn't recognize a mmap operation as using any memory at all. Could be argued to be cheating, but isn't that part of what makes it fun? :)

Comment: Just Curious if the challenge is online can you share link. normally python has roughly 5 to 10 time more allotted time and  2x? extra memory.

Comment: @Anonymous1847 With "avoid reading one by one", I guess you mean one *character* at a time like my function does? I don't care if something like `finditer` does that internally. If it reads let's say 4 KB (one memory page) at a time, that'd be ok, still O(1) and relatively small.

Comment: @venky__ [Here's my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/252059/219610) where I could write a solution that takes only O(1) space *if* I had a good way to do what I'm asking for here. The link to the problem is in the question there. That's the case I mentioned to DaniMesejo  above. Like I said it's not a case where I *can't* do it but where I don't *want* to. In that case there are actually only up to 100 numbers. But imagine cases with *millions* of numbers (and a memory limit let's say below 1 MB).

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019503/how-to-read-tokens-without-reading-whole-line-or-file

Comment: By the way instead of using read(1) you could increase it to read(10) and this certainly will speed up your current approach

Comment: @DaniMesejo That mmap+re one looks good, if it indeed doesn't take much memory. So I guess the `finditer` documentation lied to me (or at least is misleading) when it said it wants a string. And yes, I already tried reading larger chunks and using `.split()` on them and re-joining appropriately, but that became a nightmare. That's what I meant when I said I used n=1 to make handling the data easier.

Comment: @python_learner Why/how would they "not count this as memory"? I don't think that's true.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I realized the question was linked in code review, and reading inputs is not considered as part of your algorithm's memory, if your code fails its most likely your algorithm needs working, I am of course talking from personal experience

Comment: @python_learner I guess you mean like Topcoder or LeetCode, where you really don't read the data but would be given a list of ints already? Yeah, in those cases I wouldn't count the memory, either. But what I'm asking about here and what the question of that code review is about, that includes reading the input, so there it does count.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Hrmpf, got that mmap+re one to work, but only with `bytes`, not with `str`. So that's not optimal, though for the stated usage (coding challenges with ASCII numbers and whitespace) it suffices. Will have to experiment for speed and memory usage...

Comment: So would a solution using read(n) with n > 1 will help you?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Perhaps. Depends on how complicated/fast it is :-)

Comment: @DaniMesejo I can of course read larger chunks and then still process them one character at a time. That makes it faster, but also even more complicated. I've done some benchmarks now, irritatingly my original generator seems to be only about ten times slower than `file.read().split()` (not a valid solution for the question, but I'm taking it as baseline for how fast a solution could possibly be).